# Redirect to previous page Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a web app which has a log-in option on separate pages. However when I log in, I get sent back to the home page instead of going to back to the page I was on. I am using the default login/log-out pages provided by Spring Security.

Here's my HttpSecurity configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/*").hasRole("Admin")
    .antMatchers("/manager").hasAnyRole("Admin", "Manager")
    .antMatchers("/sales").hasAnyRole("Admin", "Manager", "Sales")
    .antMatchers("/checkout").authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().permitAll()
    .and().logout().permitAll()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Main idea how to implement requirements explain in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login), which include examples source of code. You need only change this method

```
protected void handle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final 

Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + request.getRequestURI());
        return;
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, request.getRequestURI());
}`
```

in  `MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class

Comment: With the implementation of this code after logging in I get forwarded to 'project/project/login' instead of going back to the 'project/previousPath'.